# Button colour .setBackgroundColour() onclick with delay

Tags: java

```
if(characterArray[i] == '4')
{
    btn3.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF);//bright blue
    timeDelay(300);
    btn3.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00008B);// dark blue
}
```

I'm trying to change the colour of a button when it is clicked and have it return to its original colour after a delay. I can get it to change colour but if I use a delay and then have it return to original it seems to skip the part where it changes to its new colour.
I'm using .setBackgroundColor().
Any help appreciated.

Comment: " I can get it to change colour but if I use a delay and then have it return to original it seems to skip the part where it changes to its new colour". Show, don't tell. If you are having problems to begin with, you are generally not a trustworthy source of information about what you think you are doing. Post code. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: Please show us the code you use  to change these colors to help you fix it.

Comment: You should post your code... is this really java or javascript? If java, then what object has setBackgroundColor function?

Comment: I'm not looking for a coding service, but if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. I'm lousy at java having come to it from a c background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
handler.postDelayed(r, 5000);

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        changeToOrigColor();
    }
};
```

Color changes in five seconds. If you are looking for gradual change of color, please see animations!

Comment: if(characterArray[i] == '4')
                            {
                                btn3.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF);//bright blue
                                timeDelay(300);
                                btn3.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00008B);// dark blue
                               

                            }

Answer (score 0):

```
public void timeDelay(long t) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(t);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
} char[] characterArray = strIncom.toCharArray();
                    for (int i = 0; i < characterArray.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(characterArray[i] == '1')
                        {
                            btn0.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);//bright yellow
                            colour0();
                            timeDelay(1000);
                            //btn0.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFD700);//dark yellow
                        }

                        if(characterArray[i] == '2')
                        {

                            btn1.setBackgroundColor(0xFF7CFC00);//bright green
                            colour1();
                            timeDelay(1000);

                        }
                        if(characterArray[i] == '3')
                        {
                            btn2.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);

                            colour2();
                            timeDelay(1000);
                        }
                        if(characterArray[i] == '4')
                        {
                            btn3.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF);//bright blue

                            colour3();
                            timeDelay(1000);
                        }

                    }


                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please, don't paste your code in the answer section, edit your question by adding it there instead.